# Solving the equation $e^{x}-2^{x}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve

$e^{x}-2^{x}=1$

This came from one of my HS students, who was hoping to solve it algebraically. We graphed the first term vs the 2nd and third and see -

[image]

Which helped to understand there is a solution, and only one. By simply substituting 1 and then 2 for X, we had already concluded, but graphed for confirmation. Aside from staring at this for the last few days, we are not finding even a first step beyond this. The student is a sophomore, but our curriculum goes to AP Calculus, so if the answer is that there is no algebraic solution, but we need calculus to solve, that's fine.
He got this from a friend, and offered no background beyond that.

Comment: You will need numerical merhods or perhaps this can be solved with the Lambert-W-function.

Comment: Thank-you. Is there a simple explanation of why this can't be manipulated algebraically? e.g. "an equation of the form ....... needs to be solved by other method"?

Comment: I have no proof for that (and I do not know whether it can be proven at all). But an "$x$" in an exponent can usually only be removed by taking the logarithm (unless a solution can be easily guessed). But there is no rule to logarithm a sum, hence I do not see a possibility to solve this.

Comment: FYI, a more precise estimate is x≈1.1867370596363374. IMHO there's no closed-form solution (except you come up with home-brew functions that just encode the problem).

Comment: Maybe one way to see why this equation may not be able to be solved algebraically is that after the substitution $y=e^x$ it reduces to $y-y^{\log(2)}-1=0$. Given that even quintic equations, which have nice integer powers, cannot be reliably solved algebraically, there is no reason to expect that an equation that has $\log(2)$ as one of its powers would be any easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection, it is clear that the solution is just above $x=1$. Using Taylor series
$$e^x-2^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e-2 \log ^n(2)}{n!} (x-1)^n$$

Truncate to some order and use series reversion
$$x=1+t+\frac{t^2 \left(2 \log ^2(2)-e\right)}{2 (e-2\log (2))}+O\left(t^3\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac{3-e}{e-2 \log (2)}$$

This very truncated series gives $x=1.18199$; adding one more term would give $x=1.18780$.

A bit better would be to look at the zero of function
$$f(x)=x-\log(1+2^x)$$
$$f(x)=(1-\log (3))+(x-1) \left(1-\frac{2 \log (2)}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{9} (x-1)^2 \log^2(2)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ and series reversion gives
$$x=1+u-\frac{u^2 \log ^2(2)}{6\log (2)-9}+O\left(u^3\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad u=\frac{3 (\log (3)-1)}{3-2 \log (2)}$$

This gives $x=1.18666$ while Newton method would give $x=1.18674$

Answer (score 1):

As noticed we need to use numerical methods or Lambert W-function to obtain the solution but as a first step we should prove rigorously that only one solution exists (note that the graph can give an insight but it doesn't suffices as a proof).

At this aim let consider

$$f(x)=e^x-2^x-1 \implies f'(x) =e^x-2^x\log 2>0$$

indeed

$$e^x-2^x\log 2>0 \iff 2^{x\log_2 e}-\frac{2^x}{\log_2 e}\iff (\log_2 e)2^{x\log_2 e}-2^x>0$$

therefore since $f(1)=e-3<0$ and $f(2)=e^2-5>0$ by [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) only one root exists in the interval $x\in(0,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: We have:

$e^x-1=2^x$

If you do not want to use logarithm you can use expansion of $e^x $ and $2^x$:

$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$2^x=(1+1)^x=1+x+\frac{x(x-1)}{2!}\cdot 1^2+\frac{x(x-1)(x_2)}{3!}\cdot 1^3+\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{4!}\cdot 1^4+\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Taking term with higher powers on both sides give more accurate result; for example taking power 4 on both sides we finally get following equation:

$6x^3+x^2+10x-24+0$

where $x=1.188$ almost satisfies it. However the solution of theses equations is not simple and numeric solutions are much easier.